# Android CustomTabsIntent - how to stay in the browser for further redirects?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-customtabs

I currently use CustomTabsIntent to open a browser-tab despite the presence of another app that supports a given deep link:

```
class UrlOpener {
    private var mClient: CustomTabsClient? = null
    private var mSession: CustomTabsSession? = null

    private val mConnection: CustomTabsServiceConnection = object : CustomTabsServiceConnection() {
        override fun onCustomTabsServiceConnected(
            name: ComponentName,
            client: CustomTabsClient
        ) {
            mClient = client
            // Warm up the browser process
            client.warmup(0 /* placeholder for future use */)
            // Create a new browser session
            mSession = client.newSession(CustomTabsCallback())
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName) {
            mClient = null
            mSession = null
        }
    }

    init {
        CustomTabsClient.getPackageName(context, null)?.let {
            CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService(context, it, mConnection)
        }
    }

    fun openInAppBrowserTab(url: String) {
        val customTabsIntent = CustomTabsIntent.Builder(mSession)
            .build().launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(url))
    }
}
```

This works fine for opening a browser tab. In the flow after opening the website, there is another redirect to the url supported by the app though, which then actually opens the app.
Is there a way to configure a CustomTabsIntent in a way that it always stays inside the browser, even when facing redirects that would be handeled by another installed app?

I tried looking through the parameters that can be set in the CustomTabsIntentBuilder, but I couldn't find anything useful there..